# Apple installer issue in terminal where -target keeps saying; error cannot find Volume

Tags: command-line, bash, script

I am trying to use the Apple Installer commands to install a package and the output is that it was successful, however, the end result is that nothing actually happens meaning the package never gets installed or launched. Could someone please look over the commands and tell me what is wrong or try it themselves to see what could be the issue?

```
#Machines must have cURL installed as a prerequisite to download software from internet or FTP server 

#grab files from www.teamviewer.com or custom FTP server
curl -O http://download.teamviewer.com/download/TeamViewerHost.dmg

#Mount and Install TeamViewer
hdiutil mount /Users/TeamViewer/Downloads/TeamViewerHost.dmg
sudo cp -R "/Volumes/TeamViewerHost" /Applications

#Run installer
sudo installer -package /Applications/TeamViewerHost/Install\ TeamViewerHost.pkg -target "/Volumes/TeamViewerHost"

#Unmount package
cd ~
hdiutil unmount "/Volumes/TeamViewerHost/"
```

Or what else I have tried is this with the same result:

```
#Machines must have cURL installed as a prerequisite to download software from internet or FTP server 

#grab files from www.teamviewer.com or custom FTP server
curl -O http://download.teamviewer.com/download/TeamViewerHost.dmg

#Mount and Install TeamViewer
hdiutil mount /Users/TeamViewer/Downloads/TeamViewerHost.dmg

#Run installer
sudo installer -package /Volumes/TeamViewerHost/Install\ TeamViewerHost.pkg -target "/Volumes/TeamViewerHost"

#Unmount package
cd ~
hdiutil unmount "/Volumes/TeamViewerHost/"
```

If I change the target to where I want it to be installed to such as:

```
sudo installer -package /Volumes/TeamViewerHost/Install\ TeamViewerHost.pkg -target /Users/User/Applications
```

I get an error that says Installer: error trying to locate volume.

The need is to install TeamViewer over SSH through terminal, but Installer is not playing nice. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: you already got correctly answered this question on the stackoverflow  http://stackoverflow.com/a/25409760/771480

Comment: I was guided over here and thought to answer with the provided answer. It works thank you